# Process suspended when reading from pipe - linux

Tags: c, linux, posix, pipe

I've written the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define BUFF 200


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char write_buffer[BUFF];
    char read_buffer[BUFF];

    strcpy(write_buffer, "This string supposed to be sent from parent to child");

    int fds[2];
    pid_t pid;

    if ((pid=fork())==-1) {
        perror("fork error");
    }

    if (pipe(fds)==-1) {
        perror("pipe error");
    }


    else if (pid==0) { // child


        int bytes;
        if ((bytes=read(fds[0], read_buffer, BUFF))==-1) {
            perror("read error");
        }
        else {
            printf("read %d bytes from pipe\n", bytes);
        }
    }

    else { // parent

        if (write(fds[1], write_buffer, strlen(write_buffer))==-1) {
            perror("write error");
        }

        printf("FLAG to check if write() went through\n"); // this will print!

        wait(NULL);
    }
}
```

The simple code above is an attempt to send data through a pipe, from a parent process to a child process.
Problem is, the execution is suspended for some reason...
The child process blocked at the read() system call (or at least it seems to be), and the parent just sits there, waiting for it to finish, but that never happens.
What is the problem here? clearly, the parent process has enough time to write `write_buffer` to the pipe, so the child process won't call read() on an empty pipe.

Comment: You do not need to `sleep`.  The comment `this should give the parent more than enough time to write` is indicative of a fundamental misunderstanding.  Unless you are explicitly using non-blocking file descriptors (and this code is not), the OS handles the details for you (reads block until data is ready, writes block until there is room to write data).  Omit the sleep.

Comment: OK, an edit has been made to the code. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You `fork` and then you create the pipe so each process is going to its own set of pipes that don't talk to each other.

Just switch the code around and call `pipe` before `fork` and you should be good to go.

Also, though it probably won't matter here, get in the habit of reading and writing in a loop.  `read` & `write` are not guaranteed to get nor put all the data you request in one call.  Likewise, close your pipes after you done.  Closing the write end of the pipe will signal to the reader that the end-of-file has been reached.

```
while (read(fds[0], read_buffer, sizeof(read_buffer)) > 0) 
{
    //process bytes read
}
```

Comment: This is correct, but merely swapping the order will not produce correct code.  The child's read is going to block since neither the child nor the parent have closed the write side of the pipe.

Comment: Nope, the child's `read` will read whatever is in the pipe (possibly a short read) and end since OP isn't reading until EOF anyway.  But I will amend the answer anyway since it is a valid point in general.